# Installing the 'scde' package does not work

Tags: r, github, installation, zip, package

I'm tring to install this R package :
http://pklab.med.harvard.edu/scde/index.html

https://github.com/hms-dbmi/scde

I used several methods

First, I downloaded a zip file. When I install it, R says it is OK

```
install.packages("~/scde-master.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/wagnerc/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
```

But then I'm unable to load it, saying it is not installed.

```
> library(scde)
Error in library(scde) : 
  ‘scde’ n'est pas un nom correct de package installé
```

I tried using github, but then I got an error

```
library(devtools)

dev_mode(on=T)

Dev mode: ON

install_github("hms-dbmi/scde")

    Downloading GitHub repo hms-dbmi/scde@master
    Installing scde
    Skipping 1 packages ahead of CRAN: BiocParallel
    "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.1/bin/i386/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
      "C:/Users/wagnerc/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpwPkw6R/devtools5bbc140a3cc9/hms-dbmi-scde-4494544"  \
      --library="C:/Users/wagnerc/Documents/R-dev" --install-tests 
    * installing *source* package 'scde' ...
    ** libs
    *** arch - i386
    Warning: l'exécution de la commande 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="scde.dll" OBJECTS="bwpca.o jpmatLogBoot.o matSlideMult.o pagoda.o"' renvoie un statut 127
    ERROR: compilation failed for package 'scde'
    * removing 'C:/Users/wagnerc/Documents/R-dev/scde'
    Erreur : Command failed (1)
```

Comment: I would suggest that you run `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English")`, rerun your code and post the resulting English error messages.

Comment: thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately, this command does not work (maybe because I work on Windows). But I would find the translation.
First : `‘scde’ is not a valid installed package.`
Then it is said that the commande 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="scde.dll" OBJECTS="bwpca.o jpmatLogBoot.o matSlideMult.o pagoda.o"' returns a status of 127.

Comment: It works on my windows system.